# how can I Automate Picker Wheel Controls in Appium python testing

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop

I am trying to Automate picker wheel in Appium python testing. I have tried in this way but not working.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']").sendkey("5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']").sendkey("24")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']").sendkey("1990")`

here is the screensot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Bm8.png

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: here is the error "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']").sendkey("10")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkey' " .

Comment: Do you have an image or snapshot of the html from appium desktop ?

Comment: I have added the screensot above

Comment: Refer to the answer

Comment: here is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Bm8.png

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Appium [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/) on send keys
 

It should be send_keys , not sendkey

```
driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('SomeAccessibilityID').send_keys('Hello world!')
```

Comment: I have change my code . But still not working driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']").send_keys("4")  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']").send_keys("12") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']").send_keys("PM")

Comment: What is the error and the snapshot of the element from inspector

Answer (score 0):

> I have change my code . But still not working driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']").send_keys("4") driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']").send_keys("12") driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']").send_keys("PM")

I think your index is not like the order in test

Make sure

- the first index is the hour,
- the second one is minutes and
- the last one is AM/PM